# Positioning bug when initialising animated div

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I am creating a horizontal menu bar with a series of links. Underneath the current page link, there is an absolutely positioned div with a fixed size and a black background. When any of the other links are hovered over, this "selection indicator" slides across to underneath the hovered link. I have managed to create this effect as desired.

However, I am having an issue with the position of the "selector" div when the page first loads. For some reason the div sets it's initial position to exactly 5 pixels left of where it is supposed to be (underneath the current page link). I am using the same code to initialise the div as I am for the animation itself, and the bug only appears when the page is loaded. As soon as a link is hovered over, the "selector" slides into the correct positions until the page is refreshed/reloaded.

A working example of the menu (and the bug) can be found at [www.jamiedavies.me](http://www.jamiedavies.me/)

Here is the html structure of my navigation bar:

```
<header>
    <h1>Main Title</h1>
    <nav id="mainNav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#1" title="Link1" class="current">Link1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#2" title="Link2">Link2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#3" title="Link3">Link3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#4" title="Link4">Link4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="pageSelector"></div>
</header>
```

Here is the related CSS:

```
nav#mainNav {
   position: absolute;
   right: 0px;
   top: 63px;
}

nav#mainNav ul li {
   display: inline;
   list-style-type: none;
   margin-left: 35px;
}

div#pageSelector {
   height: 5px;
   left: -999px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 91px;
   visibility: hidden;
   width: 25px;
}
```

And here is the javascript/jquery code that is responsible for animating the selector:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {

    var offset = $( "header" ).offset().left;

    $( "#pageSelector" ).css( "visibility", "visible" );

    $( "#mainNav li" ).find( "a" ).each( function( i ) {
        $( this ).mouseover( function( e ) {
            var l = $( this ).offset().left - offset;
            var w = $( this ).width();
            $( "#pageSelector" ).animate( {
                left: l,
                width: w
            }, 175, "swing" );
        } );
    } );

    $( "#mainNav" ).mouseleave( function( e ) {
        $( "#pageSelector" ).animate( {
            left: $( "#mainNav li a.current" ).offset().left - offset,
            width: $( "#mainNav li a.current" ).width()
        }, 175, "swing" );
    } );

    $( "#mainNav" ).mouseleave();
} );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
```

instead of

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
```

Because, it seems the animation script completed execution before the other elements are supposedly loaded first, such as your special fonts and graphics, which most probably caused a mathematical error in alignment computation.

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: I can confirm that this solution has fixed the problem - thank you very much!